# Gnuplot line color change (multi colored lines), dashed lines, various pointer style for replot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have plotted this graph. I would like to change colors of lines as well as to make plot beautiful using dashed lines or point style setup via replot in Gnuplot.
[image: graph]

I have used below code for `gnuplot` syntax:

```
gnuplot=./results.gnuplot >> $gnuplot
echo set style data lines >> $gnuplot
echo set output \"/dev/null\" > $gnuplot
echo set title \"Parameters\" >> $gnuplot
echo set terminal pdf  >> $gnuplot
echo set xlabel \"threshold\" >> $gnuplot
echo set ylabel \"Score\" >> $gnuplot
echo set key bottom right >> $gnuplot
echo set xrange \[0\:0.1\] >> $gnuplot
```

I have used plot and replot to plot data:

```
if [[ $COUNTER == 0 ]]; then
echo plot \"$root/values.txt\" using 1:0 title \"$root\" with lines \
>> $gnuplot                     
else
echo replot \"$root/values.txt\" using 1:0 title \"$root\" with lines \
>> $gnuplot
fi
let COUNTER++
```

To generate plotting file:

```
echo set output >> $gnuplot
echo replot >> $gnuplot
gnuplot $gnuplot > ./results.pdf
```

Replot line is very important because itself alone plots 6 lines from data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this using the combination of `with lines`, `with points`, `line color`, `pointtype`, `linetype` etc... Eg.:

```
plot sin(x) with lines, sin(x)**2 with points, cos(x) with lines dashtype 2, cos(x)**2 with lines linecolor 6, cos(x/2) with points pointtype 4
```

or shorter

```
plot sin(x) wl, sin(x)**2 wl, cos(x) wl dt 2, cos(x)**2 wl lc 6, cos(x/2) ws pt 4
```

[image]

You can see a short summary of the avaiable styles of the current terminal typing `test`:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is work for plot. I have used replot and looking for suggestion using replot

Comment: The pair `plot "something1" \ replot "something2"` works as `plot "something1"+"something2"`, therefore you also can use the `dt`, `pt` etc. keywords in replot "something2"; however there is no way to have affect on the content of "something1".